# What kind of problems in the world can be classified into PSPACE categories?

Tags: np-hard, np, decision-problem

For instance can we categorize the following problems into NP-Hard ?

1. Is the Universe finite ?
2. Is there life after death ?
3. What came first, the chicken or the egg ?

My question is more around what can be modelled into the PSPACE category of problems ?

Comment: The way you are using the term PSPACE (a space complexity class) does not make sense here. You want to know what kind of problems/questions can be classified/studied in terms of complexity (into such classes like P, NP, PSPACE, etc.)?

Comment: Saddened to see a downvote. This was genuine doubt. :( Yes @tnnick. Let me modify the question a bit.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this question is meant seriously, but it actually relates to a common misunderstanding in computability.

Recall that a problem is formally captured as a formal language, i.e. a set of strings that are, intuitively, the "yes" instances of the problem.
For example,
$$SAT=\{\langle \phi\rangle: \phi \text{ is a satisfiable Boolean formula}\}$$
Then, a "solution" for the problem is a Turing machine that receives an encoding of the input $\phi$, and answers either "yes" or "no".

Now, often in "real life" you encounter problems that are just a "single" question, and therefore their language doesn't depend on the input, and is either universal or empty. For example all the questions you asked:

*"Is there life after death?"* --
This is not a well-defined question, since you need to formally define what is life and what is death, but assume for the sake of argument that you did define it somehow, then if the answer is "yes", then a TM that always says "yes" is correct.
Otherwise, a TM that always says "no" is correct.

In this sense, the problem is trivial. It's certainly in P, but it's also way below P. It's regular. It's even "less" than regular.

The same goes for your two other questions.

The moral of this is the following important observation: complexity theory is relevant only as long as you don't fix the input. Once the input is fixed, then the answer is fixed, and the definition of complexity theory become redundant.

So in order to make these problems interesting, you need to formalize what the computationally-interesting parts are, and study them.

Comment: Thanks @Shaull. It could have been a seemingly silly question on my part. But yes, as long as one can formalize the problem well, it would make sense to apply the pspace categorization.